# ¿Cómo Habilitar ScrollView en Constraints Layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Buenas, mi problema es saber como implementar un scrollview en constraints layout. He probado de varias maneras y nada. Aquí dejo unas imágenes a modo de ejemplo un constraint layout con dos button, la idea es poder hacer scroll para bajar y ver el segundo.
[image: De que forma se implementa el ScrollView para no romper el Constraints Layout?]

[image: La vista del xml]

Comment: Puedes añadir el código en vez de las imágenes?

Comment: ten en cuenta que aun están desarrollando constrains layout, si es para realizar pruebas vale, pero si es para sacar app, puedes llevarte alguna sorpresa no deseada. Activa las actualizaciones de Android Studio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deberías de englobar el `ConstraintLayout` con el `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        .....
        .....
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Antes había un bug con respecto a englobar un `ConstraintLayout` dentro de un `ScrollView` pero parece que ya ha sido corregido. Lo puedes ver en la revisión de **[Android 2.2 Preview 2](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview2available)**.

> ConstraintLayout ahora funciona correctamente dentro de ScrollView

Comment: Gracias por responder. Lo probé de esa manera en un proyecto armado pero me enrede. Pensaba que no iba a haber mas anidamientos con el constraints layout por lo que les escuche decir a los de google pero creo que no sera del todo cierto.
Saludos!

Comment: @DanielLópez Simplemente asegúrate de tener la versión 2.2.2 de Android Studio instalada para no tener problemas con su implantación.

Comment: Hola @DanielLópez, he visto que estás intentando aceptar las dos respuestas a la vez. Realmente solo puedes aceptar una respuesta al mismo tiempo, la cual tendría que representar a la solución a tu problema. Sin embargo, puedes votar positivo a todas las respuestas que consideres que también te han sido útiles. Para ello, puedes utilizar la flecha de arriba a la izquierda de cada respuesta.

Comment: Ahhh Soy nuevo aquí así que ese el motivo  xD

Comment: Si, no hay ningun problema, el ConstraintLayout por si solo no es scrolleable, asi que puedes ponerlo dentro del ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

NO tiene que ver con código ni con el layout simplemente **[actualiza tu Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)**

revisa las [características de Android Studio 2.2 (preview 2)](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview2available)

> ConstraintLayout: version 1.0.0-alpha2: ConstraintLayout now works
>   properly inside ScrollView

Comment: Si está actualizado. Solo quería saber la manera correcta de hacerlo.